# Change status in Invoice using API - Quickbooks

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am working on Integrating Invoices to Quickbooks. I would like to change the Invoice status to Paid when creating/updating Invoice to Quickbook.

I don't find any way to update the Status of Invoice.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Invoices get marked paid in QuickBooks by applying a payment to the invoice.

Thus, you should review the documentation on creating PAYMENTS in QuickBooks:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/payment

Comment: I have found another way that I add a Deposit (full invoice amount) in Invoice when status is Paid in another app. So In Quickbooks, it will mark the Invoice as Paid.
Is it ok to add like this or Do I have the use Payments?

Comment: Was a payment made, or was a deposit made?  If a payment was made, add a payment. If a deposit was made, add a deposit.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when adding an invoice using the API its marked as paid / deposited even though i didn't add any payment.

To create an unpaid invoice I added:  `"LinkedTxn" => [],`

so my request looks like this:

```
$theResourceObj = Invoice::create([
          "Line" =>  $lineArray,
          "DocNumber" => $invoiceid,
          "GlobalTaxCalculation" => "TaxExcluded",
          "ExchangeRate" => $exchangerate, #0.856164,
          "LinkedTxn" => [],
          "TxnDate" => $date, #2019-11-15
          "DueDate" => $duedate,#2019-12-21
          "InvoiceLink" => "https://my.webshop.com/?invoice=".$invoiceid,
          "CustomerRef"=> [
                "value"=> $quickbID
          ],
          "CurrencyRef"=> [
                "value"=> $currencycode #EUR
          ]
       ]);
```

Once invoice is added you should add the payment/s.
this will mark payment as paid.